# Applying a function at a cumulative week level in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

Below is my dataframe(df), where i have instances at a weekly level of expected and actuals

[image: Original Dataframe]

I need to apply the below Python code function to calculate the auc at a cumulative weekly level.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
   def auc_group(df):
      y_hat = df.expected
      y = df.actual
      return (roc_auc_score(y,y_hat))
```

For each week, the scoring should happen for all records until that week, so that result should look something like below.

[image: Expected result]

While it is simple to apply the function for each week, applying that to do a cumulative score, considering all the records until that week, has been a challenge for me. Any help in solving this is appreciated.

Comment: What does `roc_auc_score` do?

Comment: it calculate the auc score after considering expected and actuals. it come with sklearn library

Comment: Can you provide your dataframe as dataframe constructor and the import for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need cumulative count and cumulative `roc_auc_score` use:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

s1 = df['week'].value_counts().sort_index().cumsum()

expected, actual = [],[]
def f(x):
    expected.extend(x['expected'].tolist())
    actual.extend(x['actual'].tolist())
    return roc_auc_score(actual, expected)

s2 = df.groupby('week').apply(f)

df = (pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1, keys=('count of records','AUC'))
        .rename_axis('week')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   week  count of records       AUC
0    10                 2  1.000000
1    11                 6  0.500000
2    12                10  0.583333
```

If need cumulative count and roc_auc_score per groups (not cumulative) use:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

s1 = df['week'].value_counts().sort_index().cumsum()
s2 = df.groupby('week').apply(lambda x: roc_auc_score(x.actual,x.expected))

df = (pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1, keys=('count of records','AUC'))
        .rename_axis('week')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   week  count of records       AUC
0    10                 2  1.000000
1    11                 6  0.166667
2    12                10  0.750000
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @jezrael. The first solution you provided is what i was looking for. Just for clarification, when we call group by, does it always maintain order, meaning first project week 10, then week 11 and so on?

Comment: @jorge - exactly like says. Because `groupby` sorting by `week`, so processng first `10`, then `11` and last `12` in sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()

data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(iris.target, columns = ['target']), 
pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns = iris.feature_names)], axis = 1)

def target_replace(x):
    for i in [0,1,2]:
        if x == i:
            return(iris.target_names[i])
    
data.target = data.target.apply(target_replace)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).